# Combinatorics And Counting

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

A class consists of 3 boys and 6 girls willing to form 3 groups of 3 called Groups A, B, C.
How many ways are there to assign 9 of them to Groups A, B C?

I started with $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$
but it seems faulty because there might be 3! ways to label each group formed as A, B, C. Not sure.

Part 2. How many ways are there to have exactly 1 group with all boys?

Comment: Does each group need to have a boy and two girl in them?  If not, what's the importance of them...?

Comment: Well, that's another part of the question. For this part, I just need to know how to put them into groups irrespective of gender.

Answer (score 0):

If each group needs to have a boy in them, pick the boys first: the A group has three choices, the B group has two choices, the last, C 1. Independently, pick the first and girl in each group, that's 6*5/2 , 4*3/2, 2*1/2 so $$3! \cdot 6! \over 2^3$$

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.
Now, what if I wanted a group to have all boys?

Comment: Three boys and a group of three... there's not a lot of choice: it can either be A or B or C, so 3. Then you need

Comment: .......then I need?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt even realize the system sent that. So, you have two groups left, fill in the first, that'll 6!/3!*3! and that's it because you only have three girls left...

Answer (score 0):

The answer $\binom{9}{3,3,3}=\frac{9!}{(3!)^3}$ that you've written down already includes this possibility; you can view it as choosing three people out of nine, and putting them in group A; of the remaining six choose three more, for group B; then the remaining three are group C. This means the count is
$$
\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}=\frac{9!}{3!\cdot 6!}\cdot\frac{6!}{3!\cdot3!}\cdot\frac{3!}{3!\cdot0!}=\frac{9!}{3!\cdot3!\cdot 3!}=1680.
$$
If you wanted to count the number of ways to group people up without caring about labels, you could do so by putting them in labeled groups, then dividing by the number of ways to label the groups; this would yield
$$
\frac{9!}{3!\cdot3!\cdot3!\cdot3!}=280.
$$

Comment: Thank you.
From your first solution, you put the first three in group A. What if they were moved replaced with those in B and vise versa? Is that already accounted for?

Comment: That's already accounted for: we didn't "put the first three in group A" -- we just _chose the members for group A first_.

Comment: Okay, I honesty believe your method, as that is what I think it is. But I was presented with this example: Say the question is to make two distinctly named groups of 2 out of 4 objects A, B, C, D. Combined Choices are Group1 (AB, AC, AD) Group2 (BC, BD, CD)    This is consistent with using $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$
 Now AB should be able to be in group2. All elements in group1 should at some point be allowed to take labels in group2. This is resolved by multiplying by 2!.

Comment: That is not consistent with using $\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}$.  You have listed only three possibilities: group 1 is AB and group 2 is CD; group 1 is AC and group 2 is BD; and group 1 is AD and group 2 is CD.  But $\frac{4!}{2!\cdot2!}=6$, not three.  You have left off half the options.

Comment: The method is this: first, choose __any 2__ to be in group 1.  This can be done as either AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, or CD.  Once you've determined these, you choose 2 of the remaining 2 to be group 2; this can of course only be done in one way.

Comment: Exactly what I was just thinking. Each set of events should contain  2 packets, not 1. Since a group will have a complement at any given time. Thanks for the confirmation. 
Now, how about: How many ways are there to assign students to these groups such that every group includes 1 boy?

Comment: Choose how to place the boys, then choose how to place the girls.  So really: find the number of ways to put one boy in group A, one boy in group B, and one boy in group C; then find the number of ways to split the girls up in to groups A, B, C of size 2; then multiply the two results, since one choice doesn't change the other.

Comment: Here's what I got $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}\cdot 3!$

Comment: That's right!  You've got it.

Comment: Then another questions wants the number of ways to have all boys in one group. I did  $\frac{6!}{3!3!}\cdot 3   $

Comment: There an argument that it should just be $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$

Comment: You were right the first time.

Comment: Okay, now the last part is, the number of ways to have a group with exactly one boy. Got any ideas? I got something, but it's not fully developed

Comment: It is against site practice to continue asking new questions in comments; rather, accept my answer to this question (if you feel that I've answered it for you), and consider posting your other questions as just that: questions!

Comment: It's under the same question. It's the last part.

Comment: But it isn't part of the question that you asked on this site.  So, either update your question to include it, or ask it as a new question.

Comment: Updated. Since it says "exactly", one group with two boys and another with one boy.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here.